# getaddrinfo() returns 127.0.0.1 for remote host

Tags: windows, loopback, getaddrinfo

I have an application which uses getaddrinfo() to translate from the hostname of a PC in a Windows Workgroup to the IPV4 address for that PC on the LAN.  (Note, I don't mean getting the address of the PC the code is running on, I mean the address of another PC on the LAN!) This has been working in the field as well as in the lab for quite some time but now I have a Windows 7 (32 bit) PC that behaves anomalously.  The hostname for this PC is "elbow".

I compiled the sample code provided by Microsoft for getaddrinfo() at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

When I run this sample code on any PC on my LAN and specify "elbow" as the hostname, getaddrinfo() returns the loopback address 127.0.0.1 instead of the correct one (192.168.1.110).  However, if I specify any other hostname getaddrinfo() returns the correct address!

At some point in the past "elbow" did NOT exhibit this behavior, so clearly something about that PC has changed to cause this behavior.  I have tried restoring the PC disk image to a point where I *think* it did not cause this behavior, but that made no change.
It also makes no difference whether the PC is hardwired or wirelessly connected to the LAN.  DHCP is enabled for all PCs on the LAN.  The behavior is persistent even with a complete power-down of all PCs, routers and switches.

Comment: My incorrect answer is gone. I see you haven't had any other activity on this question; it really is a puzzler. Good luck!

Comment: It's extremely strange!  And it's unidirectional - the oddball PC has no problem getting the correct IP for all of the other PCs.  It is as though there were some security setting making the IP "invisible".  I've searched for such a setting before, but you know, I think I'll take another look...

Answer (score 1):

Hit a similar problem and wanted to post just in case someone else found this thread.

The same thing happened on our side with a customer installed computer.  We found that the customer changed their hosts file to associate 127.0.0.1 with the pc's name... a separate program using getaddrinfo to find a certain subnetwork kept failing...they ended up renaming the computer temporarily to use this function but they also could have fixed their host file.

The hosts file on that Win 7 computer was found in /windows/system32/drivers/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this with the answer.  The elephant in the room was the ISP's DNS.  I was under the mistaken impression that my subnet was isolated from the ISPs DNS but that was not the case.  For whatever reason, their DNS is returning 127.0.0.1 for the hostname "elbow" but as soon as I renamed it to something else my problem went poof!  I also uncovered another PC that had the same problem, and renaming it fixed it too.  The thing both PCs have in common is that both had undergone OS reloads, but the problem did not become apparent until some time after those OS reloads.